# More divs inside a javascript slideshow div

Tags: html, background, slideshow

I have a container that's 1000*430 pixles, and a javascript slideshow playing inside it. However, I would like to place more boxes inside that container (so that the slideshow is more a background inside that very container). When I do now, they appear below the slideshow even though I float them left and have placed them inside the slideshow box. Any ideas?

If it's any help, I have copied the code below.

```
    <body>
    <div class="main_container">
        <div class="invisible_header"></div>

        <div class="container">

            <div class="slideshow">

              <!-- configurable script -->
            <script type="text/javascript">
            theimage = new Array();


            // The dimensions of ALL the images should be the same or some of them may look stretched or reduced in Netscape 4.
            // Format: theimage[...]=[image URL, link URL, name/description]
            theimage[0]=["img/image_still1.png", "", "Test1"];
            theimage[1]=["img/image_still2.png", "", "Test2"];
            theimage[2]=["img/image_still3.png", "", "Test3"];
            theimage[3]=["img/image_still4.png", "", "Test4"];
            theimage[4]=["img/image_still5.png", "", "Test5"];
            theimage[5]=["img/image_still6.png", "", "Test6"];
            theimage[6]=["img/image_still7.png", "", "Test7"];


            ///// Plugin variables

            playspeed=5000;// The playspeed determines the delay for the "Play" button in ms
            dotrans=1; // if value = 1 then there are transitions played in IE
            transtype='blendTrans';// 'blendTrans' or 'revealtrans'
            transattributes='23';// duration=seconds,transition=#<24
            //#####
            //key that holds where in the array currently are
            i=0;


            //###########################################
            window.onload=function(){

                //preload images into browser
                preloadSlide();

                //set transitions
                GetTrans();

                //set the first slide
                SetSlide(0);

                //autoplay
                PlaySlide();
            }

            //###########################################
            function SetSlide(num) {
                //too big
                i=num%theimage.length;
                //too small
                if(i<0)i=theimage.length-1;

                //switch the image
                if(document.all&&!window.opera&&dotrans==1)eval(        'document.images.imgslide.filters.'+transtype+'.Apply()')
                document.images.imgslide.src=theimage[i][0];
                if(document.all&&!window.opera&&dotrans==1)eval('document.images.imgslide.filters.'+transtype+'.Play()')

            }


            //###########################################
            function PlaySlide() {
                if (!window.playing) {
                    PlayingSlide(i+1);
                    if(document.slideshow.play){
                        document.slideshow.play.value="   Stop   ";
                    }
                }
                else {
                    playing=clearTimeout(playing);
                    if(document.slideshow.play){
                        document.slideshow.play.value="   Play   ";
                    }
                }
                // if you have to change the image for the "playing" slide
                if(document.images.imgPlay){
                    setTimeout('document.images.imgPlay.src="'+imgStop+'"',1);
                    imgStop=document.images.imgPlay.src
                }
            }


            //###########################################
            function PlayingSlide(num) {
                playing=setTimeout('PlayingSlide(i+1);SetSlide(i+1);', playspeed);
            }


            //###########################################
            //desc: picks the transition to apply to the images
            function GetTrans() {
                //si=document.slideshow.trans.selectedIndex;

                    if((document.slideshow.trans && document.slideshow.trans.selectedIndex == 0) || (!document.slideshow.trans && dotrans==0)){
                    dotrans=0;
                }
                else if ((document.slideshow.trans && document.slideshow.trans.selectedIndex == 1) || (!document.slideshow.trans && transtype == 'blendTrans')){
                    dotrans=1;
                    transtype='blendTrans';
                    document.imgslide.style.filter = "blendTrans(duration=1,transition=1)";
                }else{
                    dotrans=1;
                    transtype='revealtrans';
                    if(document.slideshow.trans) transattributes=document.slideshow.trans[document.slideshow.trans.selectedIndex].value;
                    document.imgslide.style.filter = "revealTrans(duration=1,transition=" +transattributes+ ")";
                }

            }
            //###########################################
            function preloadSlide() {
                for(k=0;k<theimage.length;k++) {
                    theimage[k][0]=new Image().src=theimage[k][0];
                }
            }


            </script>


            <!-- slide show HTML -->
            <form name="slideshow">

            <table border="0" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
                <td align="center">     
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    document.write('<img name="imgslide" id="imgslide" src="'+theimage[0][0]+'" border="0">')
                </script>
                </td>
            </tr>
            </table>

            </form>
            <!-- end of slide show HTML -->


            <div class="film_header"></div>
            <div class="film_container">




                <div class="meny_box"></div>


            </div>
           <div class="film_bottom"></div>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: I thought maybe I could type in a negative value for the top margins so that the boxes come back on top of the slideshow, and it works, but they now appear behind the slideshow. Doesn't work too good the either.

Comment: It is always better to create an example of your code on http://jsfiddle.net/ and post a link, cause a great number of people will not bother to go look at code like this, much less copy it create a file and try it like that.

Comment: The question is about positioning an element. So we need CSS as well to be able to judge the situation.

Answer (score 0):

I found a temporary solution by placing the slideshow below the rest of the divs, give it a negative margin-top value to pull it back up, and then set a negative z-index for it. Works for now.